# Comma in a C# statament

Tags: c#

I'm reviewing this code (written in C#):

```
string root = match.Groups[1].Value,
                secon = match.Groups[2].Success ? match.Groups[2].Value.Substring(1) : string.Empty,
                third = match.Groups[3].Success ? match.Groups[3].Value.Substring(1) : string.Empty;
```

Can someone explain the purpose of the commas?

Comment: Ugh, this is a good example of how *not* to use that syntax. This question only exists because the syntax is so hard to read and understand. With all the whitespace, the code actually would've been *shorter* had it been written in the usual way.

Comment: @TimS. is right; this is a good example of how to abuse the feature. Still, it could be worse. In early versions of Visual Basic, `Dim Curly, Larry, Moe as Stooge` meant of course that `Curly` and `Larry` were `Variant` and Moe was `Stooge`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It declares 3 variables of the type `string` named `root`, `secon` and `third` respectively. Like this:

```
int a, b, c;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a syntactic shortcut. Your example above is syntactic sugar for and is exactly the same as:

```
string root  = match.Groups[1].Value   ;
string secon = match.Groups[2].Success ? match.Groups[2].Value.Substring(1) : string.Empty ;
string third = match.Groups[3].Success ? match.Groups[3].Value.Substring(1) : string.Empty ;
```

So it saves you a little typing.

That is all.

Comment: One can also use the `var` keyword. In that case it is never allowed to put multiple declarations together with commas.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: There is *one* situation in which it is legal to put multiple declarations in one statement with `var`. Can you guess what it is?

Comment: @EricLippert I am curious, as per your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4950600/1029916) and my understanding of the language, it isn't allowed at all.

Comment: @EricLippert Do you mean if I have declared a class (or struct, interface, enum, delegate) with the funny name `var`, as in `class var { }`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: You got it! The compiler checks to see if there is already a type in scope named `var` and only if there is not does it go into implicitly typed local mode.

Answer (score 0):

They are used as a shortcut to create variables, and, in your example, all of which are of type `string`.